# How to redistribute binary programs built on modern Ubuntu so that they can be executed on any older Linux system?

Tags: build, gcc, binary

I found that if I build any binary on Ubuntu 10.10, then it doesn't execute on some older Linuxes. It is because Ubuntu uses a very new C library, called EGLIBC. Most of the desktop Linux systems use GLIBC.

I would like to know whether there is any standard method how to redistribute binary programs built on a modern Ubuntu so that they can be executed on any older Linux system ?

How to find all required dependencies (glibc  version, dynamic libraries) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on doing that, then you can not use any shared libraries; you must link with -static.

To find out what it links to from the source, look at the linker command for -lfoo switches.  To inspect a binary, run ldd on it.